# Why are there different credit rates in each country?

Tags: credit, paraguay

I live in Paraguay, and here credit rates begin at 16% and go up to 50%. In Germany you can get a loan for a lot less. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're comparing similar loan terms?

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was that it must be due to inflation, which causes such differences in many cases since a creditor needs to make back more than the rate of inflation in order not to effectively lose money. But it seems that Paraguay currently has only a very modest rate of inflation, about 3%.

Other possible reasons for different credit rates:

- Regulation or cartels, that prevent competition
- Differences in default risk

The latter is most likely. It means that if debtors are generally poor and are often completely unable to pay back the loan, or if there is no effective way to force uncooperative debtors to pay (e.g. when there are weak laws or overworked courts), then creditors will lose a lot of money to defaults and have to raise rates to compensate for this.

Comment: Almost certainly, the rest of the difference could be accounted for the shifting exchange rates. But I haven't checked.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton From a FOREX traders point of view: differing interest rates cause changes in the exchange rate ("rollover rates"), but I agree that they're probably linked without a direct cause and effect. Some country (Australia or New Zealand) once set their interest loan rates for foreigners ridiculously high (several hundred percent per annum) to boost their exchange rate, but it didn't work (traders lost faith in the currency).

Comment: Your latter point makes sense. Most debtors are poor, and there's a high risk rate where people don't pay their debts back. I wonder who then regulates those incredible credit rates.

Comment: @KennyMeyer: governments often introduce anti-usury laws that limit interes rates. Apart from that, competition in a functioning market should drive down rates to a point where they are justified by the risk and costs of the creditor.